# Gallery related to the article

Tags: 7, media

I managed to create a gallery and show it under a page (creating a view of type page).

What I really need is having one different gallery associated for each article, so I created a view of type "block", but the showed gallery is always the same, while it should related to the current article.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add to your view the Contextual Filter: Content: NiD

Click Provide Default Value and select Content ID from URL

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I can't check during the weekend, but I'll give a try ASAP.

Comment: I tried it, but once done I still don't understand how to create a gallery related to the specific article.

Comment: If you having trouble with this, Skip using views for adding a gallery to an article and just add the gallery directly on the article using something like http://drupal.org/project/galleryformatter and just add some image fields to the content type.